# Damage type of quarterstaff thrusts

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, damage-types

Is thrusting with a quarterstaff still considered as bludgeoning damage under all circumstances?  (From a simulationist standpoint, thrusting with a stave is not an unheard-of maneuver, and can be quite damaging to a target).

Note: I'm more wondering if D&D missed a damage type (i.e. something for being poked with a blunt object, vs being whacked with said blunt object), by the way.

Comment: You could always add more detail to a damage system: You could have a damage type for being hit by the flat edge of a blade, but having it slip sideways a little so that it inflicts a shallow cut as well; YOu could take into account whether the part of the body his was mostly bone or padded with muscle and fat... The game designers picked a level of abstraction they felt worked, and have stuck with it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally speaking, the damage type of a weapon is to do with how the shape of the weapon influences distribution of imparted force, rather than how you wield the weapon. 'Slashing' weapons have sharp edges, pointy weapons such as spears do 'piercing' damage, and staves, being blunt, are bludgeoning weapons.

That said, I'm guessing you've spotted that particular detail already. What you're asking about is where the line is drawn between one weapon type and another - after all, when you get right down to it, there's not a huge amount of difference between a very blunt spear and a very thin staff, right?

Well, I can't say for sure where that line is, but I do know this: Sling bullets, which are generally much smaller and less blunt than the end of a quarterstaff, do bludgeoning damage on impact. I take it from this that if you want to do piercing damage with a quarterstaff, you'll need to sharpen it into a spear, first - or have some obscure feat or magic that lets you do it, though I'm not aware of such a thing.

Answer (score 11):

It's still bludgeoning.

The three (physical) damage types are

- Piercing is hitting with a sharp point
- Slashing is hitting with a sharp edge
- Bludgeoning is hitting with a blunt weapon

If the staff has a sharp point, it's a spear. If it has a sharp edge, it's a... polearm of some sort.

---

Also, D&D combat isn't very simulationist. From a simulationist standpoint, most swords should be both piercing *and* slashing, but D&D puts most of them into only one of those two categories.

Answer (score 2):

By RAW, a weapon only does one type of weapon damage (Or two, in some cases), and cannot be made to do any other type of damage.   A Quarterstaff, no matter how it is wielded, will always do bludgeoning damage.

You could, however, ask your DM to house-rule something to allow you to use a different type of damage for using your weapon in a different way.

While I wouldn't personally allow it due to the nature of a quarterstaff, some DMs might say that yes, thrusting with a quarterstaff *does* count as piercing damage, though they are at liberty to apply penalties for using it in an unusual way (-2 to attack is typical).

Note that while it might seem like a shortsword or other piercing-type weapons should be allowed to be used as a slashing type at no penalty, that you are going against the ideal fighting style of such a blade by doing so, which is much less effective